# Object constructors inside object constructors

Tags: javascript, oop

Let's say I have the following script:

```js
var A = function() {
  this.b = "asdf";
  this.c = function() {
    this.source = "asd";
    this.data = function() {
      var response;
      $.getJSON(this.source, function(data) {
        response = data;
      });
      return response;
    };
  };
};
```

The reason I made those closures is that I have other objects and variables inside `A`, making an object-oriented app. I have some doubts regarding that script:

- How would I refer to `A.b` from inside the `A.c` method? `this` refers to the `A.c` instance, not to `A` anymore.

Note: the purpose is to, on `new A()`, generate an object like this:

```js
{
  b: "asdf",
  c: {
    source: "qwerty",
    data: {
      jsondata1: "jsonvalue1",
      jsondata2: 3,
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

but I know `instance.c` will still be a constructor function, and I have no clue how to make it an object inside another.

Comment: Can't you at least answer the first question by just trying it out? Although `new A()` won't create those properties at all. You`ll also have to call `c()` on the instance of `A`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry and thanks for the point. Sometimes Stack Overflow makes me lazy!

Comment: Btw, before you get stuck next time: [How to return the response from an **asynchronous** AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
var A = function() {
    var me = this; //<-- to let you refer to b inside the c function
    me.b = "asdf";
    me.c = new function() { // <-- added new here
        this.source = me.b + 'abc';
        this.data = function() {
            var response;
            $.getJSON(this.source, function(data) {
                response = data;
            });
            return response;
        };
    };
};

a = new A();
```

`a.b` returns "asdf" and `a.c.source` returns "asdfabc". `a.c.data` would still be the function though.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was trying to do. I wonder why it never came to my mind that I should copy `this` into a private variable.

Comment: Glad I could help. Now you just need to make a private variable inside c with the getJSON function definition and then call it a bunch of times to populate your `c.data` object